# javascript in the table does not work when it is responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, footable, stacktable.js

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    function toTimeString(seconds) {
      return (new Date(seconds * 1000)).toUTCString().match(/(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/)[0];
    }

    function startTimer() {
      var dataStartElem = jQuery(this);
      var dataStart = dataStartElem.attr('data-start');
      if (dataStart == 'false') {
        dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'true');
        var nextElem = dataStartElem.parent('td').next('.count');
        var duration = dataStartElem.attr('data-value');
        var a = duration.split(':');
        var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
        setInterval(function() {
          seconds--;
          if (seconds >= 0) {
            nextElem.html(toTimeString(seconds));
            dataStartElem.attr('data-start', 'false');
          }
          if (seconds === 0) {
            alert('time out');
            clearInterval(seconds);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
    jQuery('.timer').on('click', startTimer);
    $('table').stacktable();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

fiddle demo  https://jsfiddle.net/arra6j6h/6/

javascript timer in the table does not work and time does not appear when responsive, but all normal when not responsive

Comment: What where which not work?

Comment: javascript timer in the table, you can see fiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/arra6j6h/4/

Comment: Just hint, when window is resized, html structure is changed, so, nextElem can't be found anymore... Check generated html when window is resized... You will have to traverse up to first tr, and to target next tr and find counter...